# How can I get tab lists in fish to work like tab lists in zsh?

Tags: shell, zsh, fish

When I hit tab in zsh it will show me a list of possible completions:

```
$ ls<tab>
src/ bin/ res/ docs/
```

Then when I execute the command, the output from that command replaces what was once the list of options:

```
$ ls src/
script1.py script2.py
$
```

When I do the same in fish, it does not replace the list, but puts a new prompt line under the list, similar to the way it works in bash:

```
$ ls<tab>
src/ bin/ res/ docs/
$ ls src/
script1.py script2.py
$
```

Can I get the list replacement feature that zsh has in fish?

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible yet, but it's planned! It's tracked in http://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/291